# Hide/Show 2 forms in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Forms, `Login` and `Form1`. When I click `btnLogin_Click` on the `Login` form, it opens `Form1` with this code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 pu = new Form1(label2.Text);
    pu.Show();
    pu.FormClosing += Pu_FormClosing;
    Hide();
}

private void Pu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();            
}
```

And when I click `btnExit_Click` on `Form1`, it closes the form and opens the `Login` form by using this code:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Now what I want is to find a way that, when I click `btnExit` it **Hides** `Form1` and opens the `Login` form, and when I click the login button on the `Login` Form, it shows Form1 instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: What's the issue here?  Why can't you get it to work?

Comment: if you need 1 Form then create it durring the start of the application instead of creating each time new instance.

Comment: Just iterate the `Application.OpenForms` collection to find your already created main form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to create a class-level variable for the `Form1` instance:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    private Form1 pu;

    // code continued below...
```

And then in the button click event we will hide the login form, ensure that the `pu` instance is not null (which it could be if the user closes the form instead of clicking the button that hides the form), and show our `pu` form instance.

If the instance IS null, then it will create a new one and hook up the event handlers. We will hook up both the `VisibleChanged` and `FormClosing` events to methods that will show our login form. Note that in the `FormClosing` event, we actually *Cancel* the close and hide the form instead:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();

        if (pu == null)
        {
            pu = new Form1(label2.Text);
            pu.VisibleChanged += Pu_VisibleChanged;
            pu.FormClosing += Pu_FormClosing;
        }

        pu.Show();
    }

    private void Pu_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Only show the login form if the form1 is NOT visible
        if (!pu.Visible) Show();
    }

    private void Pu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set cancel to true to prevent the form from closing, then hide the form instead
        e.Cancel = true;
        pu.Hide();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Then the only other change you need to do is to make the form1 button `Hide` the form instead of closing it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
    }

    // rest of class code omitted...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to *find* the (hidden) instance via [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `OpenForms` property represents a read-only collection of forms
>   **owned by** the application. This collection can be searched by index
>   position or by the Name of the Form.

```
using System.Linq;

...

Form1 form = Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<Form1>()
  .LastOrDefault(); // if we have several Form1 instances, let's take the last one

if (from == null)   // no Form1 instance found, have to create one
  form = new Form1();

form.Show();
```

Comment: I just commented the same as you but...now i'm not sure,does `OpenForms` contain the hidden forms too?

Comment: @Pikoh: *Open* in the `OpenForms` is a bit misleading: it should be read as *owning*, *handle created* or alike; visible state (shown/hidden) doesn't affect `OpenForms`

Comment: Yes, that's what i think. But I think i remember something about a bug that led to hidden forms disappear from `OpenForms`, that's why i asked you

Comment: See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5545d1ed-48b7-4ee8-98ea-e005a5c68f18/how-to-find-the-hidden-forms-in-application?forum=csharpgeneral) hans passant answer. Although this is too old so maybe it is solved in newer framwork versions

Comment: @Pikoh: As I can see from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,4781
`OpenFormsInternalRemove` appears at `OnFormClosed` and `OnHandleDestroyed` only; `Hide` doesn't cause neither of these events.